# What does it mean if a post with status 200 is left waiting?

Tags: rest, express, postman, passport.js

I am doing a POST to an enpoint to authenticate users. The endopoint is "/user/login". I make a post and receive status code 200 but the Postman, and also my client, are waiting for the RES object that does not arrive.

This is a screenshot of the API call through Postman:
[image]

This is controler in server side:

```
router.post(
    '/user/login',
    passport.authenticate('local'),
    UserCtrl.getLogin,
)

getLogin =  (req, res, next) => {
        console.log("req: ", req.body)
        console.log('logged in', req.user);
        var userInfo = {
            username: req.user.username
        };
        res.json(userInfo)   
    }
```

The console prints the lines in the controller, and the user is effectively authenticated, for example:

```
req:  { username: 'fedex', password: 'fedex' }
logged in {
  _id: new ObjectId("62a8b00f468c563699d7dfc2"),
  username: 'fedex',
  password: '$2a$10$cdbh0oCBNpHxxwebsvArLOAFwetVAh5LTnQwk1Lg9kjWkjAWhfxym',
  __v: 0
}
```

probably the problem is in the invocation of the local passport strategy, but I only do the standard:

```
const strategy = new LocalStrategy(

    function(username, password, done) {

        User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err)
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username' })
            }
            if (!user.checkPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password' })
            }

            return done(null, user)
        })
    }
)
```

EDITED: If I remove the middleware where the passport.authenticate('local') is invoked, and incorporate the authentication functionality directly in the controller, it works. But what is wrong with calling passport in the route?

BEFORE (does not work):

```
router.post(
    '/user/login',
     passport.authenticate('local'),
    UserCtrl.getLogin
)
```

AFTER (adding passport authentication inside the controller, it work)

```
router.post(
    '/user/login',     
    UserCtrl.getLogin 
)
```

Comment: Are the `console.log()` lines in `getLogin` being printed?

Comment: Yes, they are being printed.

Comment: And you don't have any middleware that may be causing responses not to end?

Comment: That route has only one associated controller, which invokes the local passport strategy. Nothing else.

Comment: `res.json()` will end the response. If the response doesn't get closed, there must be an external (not shown here) reason why that happens.

Comment: Yes, before to do res.json(), the route call passport.authenticate('local'). I think that this is the issues. But i do the standar. (question edited)

Comment: `passport.authenticate()` should work just fine like that, but some parts of Passport may, if not configured correctly, cause the responses not to end (session configuration or `passport.serializeUser()`, for instance).